# How to show 'SystemFolder' property in ExitDialog with WIX?

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm trying to display 'SystemFolder' in ExitDialog using code:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="[SystemFolder]" />
```

But it fails with message:

> Product.wxs(76) : warning CNDL1077 : The
> 'WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT' Property contains
> '[SystemFolder]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another
> property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property
> reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the
> value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value
> attributes.

And, the checkbox just dispears with below code:

```
<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="[SystemFolder]" After="InstallInitialize" Sequence="execute" />
```

And, it shows empty text next to checkbox with below code:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value=" " />
<CustomAction Id="SetCheckboxText" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="[SystemFolder]" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetCheckboxText" After="InstallInitialize">
        Not Installed
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we should use `InstallUISequence` rather than `InstallExecuteSequence`

```
<CustomAction Id="SetCheckboxText" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="[SystemFolder]" />
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetCheckboxText" Before="LaunchConditions"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="[SystemFolder]" After="InstallInitialize" Sequence="ui" />` The point is that most properties set in the execute sequence aren't updated in the ui sequence (properties move between the sequences in just one direction, with just one documented exception).